# Xpath Select node until tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

How to select all node p until a node div ?

```
<div>
 <div>blbaba</div>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>b</p>
 <p>c</p>
 <p>d</p>
 <div>blbaba</div>
 <p>e</p>
 <p>f</p>
 <p>g</p>
 <p>h</p> 
 <div>blbaba</div>
</div>
```

i want a,b,c,d or e,f,g,h
i tried something like : //div/following::p[preceding-sibling::div[1]]

Answer (score 11):

Use:

```
/div/div/following::p[count(preceding::div) = 1]
```

to get `p` after 1<sup>st</sup> `div` and before 2<sup>nd</sup>. Replace `1` in expression with `2` to select `p` after 2<sup>nd</sup> `div` and before 3<sup>rd</sup>.

Comment: if my current node is the second div and i want e f g h this doesn't work because count(preceding::div) = 1 get the first div and not the next div

Answer (score 5):

`//div/following-sibling::p[preceding::div]` should get you all the p's (`a,b,c,d, e,f,g,h`)
If the div's contains different text in them, you can add some conditions. For example, getting only the a,b,c,d in the below example would be:`//div[text()='a']/following-sibling::p[preceding::div]`

Or if you have some class, category or anything else that can differentiate the div's (like class in the example): `//div[@class='peach']/following-sibling::p[preceding::div]`

```
<div>
 <div class='peach'>a</div>
 <p>a</p>
 <p>b</p>
 <p>c</p>
 <p>d</p>
 <div id='abc_123132' >b</div>
 <p>e</p>
 <p>f</p>
 <p>g</p>
 <p>h</p>
 <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Last example would be that your code is generated automatically, and you only know part of some attribute for the div. In the above example, you can select e,f,g,h like this:

`//div[contains(@id,'abc')]/following-sibling::p[preceding::div]` gets all the sibling p that are after a div with id that contains 'abc' and precede another div