# How stop on specific tag?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

How get whole text under h1 tag to the next `h1` tag?

I have class name of starting `h1` tag

```
...
<h1 class="something">...</h1>
...
<h1 ...>...</h1>
...
```

I tried: `//*[@class='something']//text()`

I want to scrapy text from all childs and siblings. I don't need text of `h1` tags. I don't know how to stop scraping to next `h1` tag.

Comment: Can there be other tags between the two `h1` ? If so, should they be captured? Should the text node they contain be captured?

Comment: Beetwen h1 tags are another tags, many tags and they should not be captured, but text of tese tags should be scrapied. I don't need text of h1 tag. Please, ask me again if I didn't understand your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xpath Select node until tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993399/xpath-select-node-until-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a proper example:

```
<root>
  <h1 class="something">.1.</h1>
  .2.
  <p>.3.</p>
  .4.
  <h1 class="other">.5.</h1>
</root>
```

This XPath 1.0 expression:

```
/root//text()[not(ancestor::h1)][preceding::h1[1][@class='something']]
```

Meaning: *"descendants text nodes of `root` element having the first preceding `h1` element with `@class` attribute equal to `'something´` and not having an ancestor `h1` element"*

And it selects

```
.2.

.3.
.4.
```

Test in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ecd4f379b13558572ffd62d0db3a3f98